# докер запустился но не работает, почему?

Tags: java, docker, boot, port

в докер закинул джарник. [image: вот содержимое Dockerfile]

потом запускаю образ, запускается без ошибок
[image: показывает что томкат запущен на порту 8085]

но когда в браузере вожу localhost:8085 -- выходит нет соединения. А если запустить в idea  работает. В чем проблема ?)) подскажите плз

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937810/docker-port-isnt-accessible-from-host

Comment: случайно порт вашего приложения не задается при запуске через параметры JVM?

Comment: а как это можно узнать? не знаю